# Why should we use the indicative in "wie ich es auch durchaus verstand, daß die Leute mich nach meinem Tod vergaßen"?

Tags: subjunctive

The question is on *vergaßen* as found in Book 2 Chapter 5 of Camus's The Stranger (Der Fremde) as translated by these two translating teams.  The passage is being narrated by the novel's main character, Meursault, who is on death row.

Uli Aumüller:

> In einem solchen Moment habe ich es wieder einmal abgelehnt, den Anstaltsgeistlichen zu empfangen. Ich hatte mich hingelegt und ahnte das Nahen des Sommerabends an einem bestimmten hellen Gelb des Himmels. Ich hatte gerade mein Gnadengesuch abgelehnt und konnte die Wellen meines Blutes gleichmäßig in mir zirkulieren fühlen. Ich hatte nicht das Bedürfnis, den Geistlichen zu sehen. Zum erstenmal seit langer Zeit habe ich an Marie gedacht. Sie schrieb mir schon lange nicht mehr. An dem Abend habe ich nachgedacht und habe mir gesagt, daß sie es vielleicht leid war, die Geliebte eines zum Tode Verurteilten zu sein. Mir ist auch der Gedanke gekommen, daß sie womöglich krank oder tot war. Das war normal. Wie hätte ich es erfahren sollen, da uns außer unseren jetzt getrennten Körpern nichts verband und aneinander erinnerte. Von dem Moment an wäre mir die Erinnerung an Marie übrigens gleichgültig gewesen. Als Tote interessierte sie mich nicht mehr. Ich fand das normal, wie ich auch sehr gut verstand, daß die Leute mich nach meinem Tod **vergaßen**. Sie hatten nichts mehr mit mir zu tun. Ich konnte nicht einmal sagen, daß der Gedanke hart war.

Georg Goyert und Hans Georg Brenner:

> In einem solchen Augenblick lehnte ich es wieder einmal ab, den Geistlichen zu empfangen. Ich hatte mich hingelegt und ahnte das Heraufkommen des Sommerabends an einer gewissen Verfärbung des Himmels. Ich hatte mein Gnadengesuch gerade abgelehnt und fühlte, wie mich die Wellen meines Blutes regelmäßig durchfluteten. Ich brauchte den Geistlichen nicht. Zum erstenmal sei langer Zeit dachte ich an Maria. Sie schrieb mir schon lange nicht mehr. An diesem Abend dachte ich nach und sagte mir vielleicht sei sie es leid geworden, die Geliebte eines zum Tode Verurteilten zu sein. Mir kam dann auch der Gedanke, daß sie vielleicht krank oder gar tot sei. Das war doch nicht ausgeschlossen. Wie hätte ich das erfahren sollen, da außerhalb unserer getrennten Körper uns nichts miteinander verband und nichts den einen an den anderen erinnerte. Von diesem Augenblick an wäre mir übrigens die Erinnerung an Maria gleichgültig gewesen. Wenn sie tot war, interessierte sie mich nicht mehr. Ich fand das ganz normal, wie ich es auch durchaus verstand, daß die Leute mich nach meinem Tod **vergaßen**. Sie hatten nichts mehr mit mir zu tun. Ich konnte nicht einmal sagen, daß das ein bitterer Gedanke war.

**QUESTION**

Can you please explain why *vergaßen* is the most fortunate (appropriate) choice rather than *vergessen* (Konjunktiv I Präsens Aktiv), *vergäßen*, or *würden vergessen*?

For the purpose of this question, please forget that the passages are translations.  That is to say, I am not asking whether they are good (faithful) translations.

**BACKGROUND**

I will set down my thoughts so you can perhaps see where I am going wrong.

I understand that *vergaßen* is present indicative and can be nothing else.

Present indicative can state either an occurrent or latent (dispositional) fact (among others, I suppose).

Occurrent is what is actually happening.  For instance, if asked where you were going, you may say:

> Ich gehe nach Hause.

You are in the process of going home.

But Meursault is not saying that people are actually in the process of forgetting him after his death.  So *vergaßen* here cannot be stating an occurrent fact.

Latent or dispositional is something that is true in general (though not necessarily now).  For example,

> People soon forget their loved ones when they are gone.

This does not say that anybody is actually gone or in the process of forgetting.  Forgetting soon is just a general thing that happens when somebody is gone, or a tendency.

But Meursault is not talking about anybody but himself.  He can die only once.  It is not a general truth that people forget him when he is gone.  People don't *tend* to forget him when he is gone.

Then what *is* he talking about?  He is stating what he understood; and that concerned a probable future occurrent fact, i.e. what he thought *would* happen after his death.

Moreover he is not committed to his understanding turning out to be true.  In the capacity of narrator, he doesn't care.  His business is only to state his understanding.

Don't we use a form of subjunctive for just this sort of thing?

As I said, this is not a question about how to translate.  But just in case anyone was curious, I am copying the French original.  Unfortunately, *oublier* is identical in indicative present and subjunctive present, for third person plural; so the text in and of itself does not shed a light on the question anyway.

> C’est à un semblable moment que j’ai refusé une fois de plus de recevoir l’aumônier. J’étais étendu et je devinais l’approche du soir d’été à une certaine blondeur du ciel. Je venais de rejeter mon pourvoi et je pouvais sentir les ondes de mon sang circuler régulièrement en moi. Je n’avais pas besoin de voir l’aumônier. Pour la première fois depuis bien longtemps, j’ai pensé à Marie. Il y avait de longs jours qu’elle ne m’écrivait plus. Ce soir-là, j’ai réfléchi et je me suis dit qu’elle s’était peut-être fatiguée d’être la maîtresse d’un condamné à mort. L’idée m’est venue aussi qu’elle était peut-être malade ou morte. C’était dans l’ordre des choses. Comment l’aurais-je su puisqu’en dehors de nos deux corps maintenant séparés, rien ne nous liait et ne nous rappelait l’un à l’autre. À partir de ce moment, d’ailleurs, le souvenir de Marie m’aurait été indifférent. Morte, elle ne m’intéressait plus. Je trouvais cela normal comme je comprenais très bien que les gens m’**oublient** après ma mort. Ils n’avaient plus rien à faire avec moi. Je ne pouvais même pas dire que cela était dur à penser.

Comment: @Jan I don't understand why my comment is gone. Do admins regularly clean up? Not that it matters a great deal. Thought you might know (be an admin) with your high reputation point.

Comment: Yes, mods semi-regularly clean up comments. In this case, it was because I flagged it as obsolete. (Although whoever cleaned it up could have deleted mine immediately, too.) Mods can be recognised by the little diamonds next to their name; currently Takkat, Loong and Wrzlprmft. Only they have the power to delete other users’ comments (i.e. I can only delete my own).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: This is not a *Konjunktiv*. See also the following sentence *sie hatten nichts mehr mit mir zu tun* - No *irrealis* here. He takes he is going to die as a future fact, not a possibility. Otherwise he'd have stated *sie hätten nichts mehr mit mir zu tun*. Also note this second sentence has no subjunctive in the French original as well. I think this second sentence is the best clue why the translator didn't choose any subjunctive form.

Try to transfer the sentence into present tense:

> Ich verstehe, dass die Leute mich nach meinem Tod vergessen. Sie haben nichts mehr mit mir zu tun.

- Which doesn't sound *quite* right, as you would expect future in the sub clause like

> Ich verstehe, dass die Leute mich nach meinem Tod vergessen *werden*. Sie werden nichts mehr mit mir zu tun haben.

(as he's not dead yet) but future tense *can* be expressed in German using the present (and note: still no Konjunktiv here).

So we have an aligned tense in both main and sub-clause.

Now back to past tense:

> Ich verstand, dass die Leute mich nach meinem Tod vergaßen

You could just as well say (and probably would in more colloquial language)

> Ich verstand, dass die Leute mich nach meinem Tod vergessen.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gave me a real, good intuitive sense of what was going on. I could even hear it: *I knew that people forgot me when I was dead.* Sounds fine even in English.  (I want to call it a version of latent truth, but that's not important).

Comment: But some questions. 1. *vergessen* in your last example is in the indicative? 2. If the translation used *würden vergessen*, would that have sounded OK too (if not as good)? 3. What if it used *vergäßen*?  Would it sound very awkward? Would it be at least grammatically well formed?

Comment: @Catomic (1) yes. (2/3) both OK and grammatically correct, but no true translation, IMHO